# I can't establish a connection to the HR Schema in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I have a Mac M1 processor so I had to work around in order to even get the SQL Developer onto my computer.  I tried using the credentials provided to me to access the HR Schema but it keeps saying that there cannot be a connection established.  I have scoured the internet for any sort of answer and nothing has helped.  Here is a screenshot of what it shows. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxQNH.jpg)

Comment: You seem confused about the different pieces in this game. You may indeed install SQL Developer on a Mac; but that's just the "client" software, which needs to connect to a database **server** to do anything useful. And there is no version of Oracle database for Mac. You can connect *remotely* to a db on a different OS (Windows or Linux), but I believe you know nothing about that, since you only mention your Mac. "Accessing" a schema like HR is not a SQL Developer issue; you need a running Oracle db server first, and it won't be on a Mac. Anything you can share about **that**?

Comment: Did you - while searching the Internet - also find this document? (https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-mac/) That's (shortly) what you should do - install VirtualBox on your Mac, download pre-built virtual machine that already contains Oracle database AND SQL Developer and start using it.